# How do I count the number of format characters in a string?

Tags: java, android, string, string-formatting

**[Update]**

I have a java string which can have format characters (those with `%`).

Is there a way to count the number of arguments which are required by this string when we call `String.format(String, args..)`

For example:

```
String placeholderString = "the %s jumped over the %s, %d times";
String.format(placeholderString, "cow", "moon", 2);
```

needs atleast `3` arguments or else it will throw `MissingFormatArgumentException`

```
String placeholderString = "the %1$s jumped over the %1$s, %2$d%% %n";
String.format(placeholderString, "cow", 2);
```

needs atleast 2 arguments.

What is an **elegant** and **efficient** way of counting the minimum number of arguments required by a string with format characters?

The reason I need this is because I want to be able to provide arguments to the method at runtime. If the arguments exceed the minimum count, I want to take those "unused" arguments and append them to the end of the string. You could also suggest alternative ways how I can go about meeting this requirement.

For example: I could provide arguments incrementally until `MissingFormatArgumentException` is not thrown. Then I can take the remaining arguments and append them. This solves my problem but I was wondering if this is the best way.

Comment: What have you considered so far? Why are you not satisfied with those options? Why is it "not good enough" to count occurrences of "%"? What "edge cases" to  you want covered?

Comment: Ok I will update my question.

Comment: The resultant String object is different than the String parameter passed to the format method. Do you want to count the number of % type characters in the passes parameter?

Comment: Something like this maybe? `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^%]%([+-]?\\d*.?\\d*)?[sdf]"); Matcher m = p.mather(input); int count = 0; while(m.find()) count++;`

Comment: Ok I hope the question is clearer now. I am not asking this question to cut down on my work. I have done enough research and just want someone who has enough knowledge (of string formats) to verify or suggest improvements. There are no other duplicates out there. Thanks :)

Comment: Can we know why you need this statistics (number of placeholders may not be same as number of arguments required by format, example: `System.out.printf("%1$d %1$d %n",42);`). Also `%n` is not placeholder for variable but for OS dependent line separator.

Comment: @Pshemo I am looking to count how many arguments are required by the placeholder string. I will be providing the arguments at runtime. If the number of arguments are more than the required, I want to be able to append them to the end of the string. I am writing a wrapper around `String.format()`

Answer (score 2):

This also accepts incorrect formats, but a format parser is clearly too expensive (i.e., too much work) - although this may be more efficient than regular expression matching. Whether this is elegant I can't say - the possible input variations are too convoluted for a slick or sleek approach.

I have changed my first solution which would merely return the minimum number of arguments since adding an argument of the wrong kind may cause an exception: you should use an argument of the class matching the conversion code. Using null results in warnings and an ugly output.

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile( "(?!<%)%" +
                  "(?:(\\d+)\\$)?" +
                  "([-#+ 0,(]|<)?" +
                  "\\d*" +
                  "(?:\\.\\d+)?" +
                  "(?:[bBhHsScCdoxXeEfgGaAtT]|" +
                  "[tT][HIklMSLNpzZsQBbhAaCYyjmdeRTrDFc])" );

Class<?> classOf( String conv ){
    if( conv.startsWith( "t" ) ){
        return Date.class;
    }
    switch( conv.charAt( 0 ) ){
    case 'b':
        return Boolean.class;
    case 'h': case 'd': case 'o': case 'x':
        return Integer.class;
    case 's':
        return String.class;
    case 'c':
        return Character.class;
    case 'e': case 'f': case 'g': case 'a':
        return Double.class;
    default:
        return Void.class;
    }
}

List<Class<?>> count( String fmt ){
    List<Class<?>> res = new ArrayList<>();
    Matcher m = pat.matcher( fmt );
    while( m.find() ){
        if( m.group(1) != null ){
            String dec = m.group(1);
            int ref = Integer.parseInt( dec );
            if( res.size() < ref ){
                while( res.size() < ref - 1 ){
                    res.add( Void.class );
                }
                res.add( classOf( m.group(3).toLowerCase() )) ;
            } else {
                Class<?> clazz = classOf( m.group(3).toLowerCase() );
                res.set( ref - 1, clazz );
            }
        } else if( m.group(2) != null && "<".equals( m.group(2) ) ){
            // ignore
        } else {
            res.add( classOf( m.group(3).toLowerCase() ));
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Tested using

```
void demo( String... formats ){
    for( String fmt: formats ){
        List<Class<?>> res = count( fmt );
        System.out.print( fmt + ": " + res.size() + ":" );
        for( Class<?> clazz: res ){
            System.out.print( " " + clazz.getSimpleName() );
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
%d: 1: Integer
%1$d: 1: Integer
the %s jumped over the %s, %d times: 3: String String Integer
the %1$s jumped over the %1$s, %2$d%% %n: 2: String Integer
Duke's Birthday: %1$tm %1$te,%1$tY: 1: Date
Duke's Birthday: %1$tm %<te,%<tY: 1: Date
%4$s %3$s %2$s %1$s %4$s %3$s %2$s %1$s: 4: String String String String
%s %s %<s %<s: 2: String String
%s %s %s %s: 4: String String String String
%2$s %s %<s %s: 4: Void String String String
```

This is the simple version, just returning the count:

```
int count( String fmt ){
    Matcher m = pat.matcher( fmt );
    int np = 0;
    int maxref = 0;
    while( m.find() ){
        if( m.group(1) != null ){
            String dec = m.group(1);
            int ref = Integer.parseInt( dec );
            maxref = Math.max( ref, maxref );
        } else if( m.group(2) != null && "<".equals( m.group(2) ) ){
            // ignore
        } else {
            np++;
        }
    }
    return Math.max( np, maxref );
}
```

Comment: this looks quite promising. For invalid formats, incorrect answer is acceptable. I will try it out, test it and keep you updated. Thanks :)

Comment: I have improved (?) the first solution. Adding arbitrary arguments may not have pleasant effects at runtime - this should be investigated thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the count you can just use the regex `(?<!%)%(?!%)`